# How can I remove the last two characters from my file?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

I'm taking out all of the coordinates from a kml file. This works, but my issue is that at the end of my file I end up with "}, }" instead of a "}}". I realize I can just manually edit the end of the file after I make it, but I'd rather have that be automatically done in the code. The commented-out section contains the code that I found in another answer, but it doesn't do anything for me.

```
import re
import os

KML = open('NYC_Tri-State_Area.kml','r')

NYC_Coords = open('NYC_Coords.txt', 'w')

coords = re.findall(r'((?<=<coordinates>).*(?=<\/coordinates>))', KML.read())

NYC_Coords.write("{")

for coord in coords:
    NYC_Coords.write("{" + str(coord) + "}, ")
...
with open('NYC_Coords.txt', 'rb+') as filehandle:
    filehandle.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    filehandle.truncate()
...

NYC_Coords.write("}")

KML.close()
NYC_Coords.close()
```

Comment: Doon't you want something like ",".join(str(coord) for coord in coords) ?

Comment: Ick.  Use a kml parser to parse it/ write it out.  Or even just `json` once you've parsed it into a python data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of suggestions for fixing your problem. First, it's probably a bad idea to use a regex to parse XML-derived documents. There are many dedicated modules for parsing KML, like [pyKML](https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/)

Second, you can eliminate the need to truncate completely by correctly generating your string. In this case, by replacing:

```
for coord in coords:
    NYC_Coords.write("{" + str(coord) + "}, ")
```

with the very simple one-liner:

```
NYC_Coords.write(', '.join('{{{}}}'.format(coord) for coord in coords))
```

You will now no longer have an extra trailing `', '` at the end of your document.

Answer (score 0):

```
for coord in coords:
    NYC_Coords.write("{" + str(coord) + "}, ")
```

Here, you write ", " at the end of every coord. But what you really want to do is write ", " *between* each coord. `join` can be used to interleave strings in this way.

```
NYC_Coords.write(", ".join("{" + str(coord) + "}" for coord in coords))
```

Now you will have no trailing comma at the end of your final coord.

Answer (score 0):

As `coords` is a list of strings, you could do:

```
NYC_Coords.write("{{{{{0}}}}}".format("}, {".join(coords)))
```

Unfortunately, your output uses the same syntax as `str.format`, so you need to escape a lot of curly braces in the template... Demo:

```
>>> coords = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> "{{{{{0}}}}}".format("}, {".join(coords))
'{{foo}, {bar}, {baz}}'
```

You could avoid the escapes with C-style string formatting:

```
>>> "{{%s}}" % "}, {".join(coords)
'{{foo}, {bar}, {baz}}'
```